# Obter o maiores elementos de uma coluna SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho 3 tabelas e tenho a seguinte questão para resolver: "Obter o "name" com maior "perce"  relacionado com o "num2" . Indique o "num2" através do "Name2"

```
 -- A (name,Num2, local)
    insert into A values ('Favela',1,'WE');
    insert into A values ('Lamosa',2,'NA');
    insert into A values ('Luz',3,'S0');


-- C (num5,num3,name2,num4)
insert into C values (2,1,'Cao',9);
insert into C values (1,2,'Gato',8);
insert into C values (1,3,'Golfinho',7);
insert into C values (3,4,'Peixe',11);

-- D (Num5, Num2, perce)
insert into D values(1,1,100);
insert into D  values(2,1,100);
insert into D values(1,3,10);
insert into D values(3,3,20);
insert into D values(2,2,60);
insert into D values(3,1,50);
insert into D values(2,3,70);
insert into D values(3,2,40);
insert into D values(2,1,0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a cláusula `EXISTS` no `WHERE` para testar se existe algum aquário com adequação maior e só mostrar o resultado caso não exista:

```
SELECT e.nome_cientifico as especie,
       a.nome as aquario
  FROM especie e
       INNER JOIN aquario_habitat ah ON ah.id_habitat = e.id_habitat
       INNER JOIN aquario a ON a.id_aquario = ah.id_aquario
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM aquario_habitat ah2
                    WHERE ah2.id_habitat = ah.id_habitat -- O que importa é o habitat
                      AND ah2.id_aquario <> ah.id_aquario -- Deve desconsiderar o mesmo aquário
                      AND ah2.adequacao > ah.adequacao); -- Caso existe de adequação maior, este deve ser descartado
```

> [**Subqueries com EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> Se a `subquery` retornar alguma linha, `EXISTS` é `TRUE`, e `NOT EXISTS` é `FALSE`

Obtemos o resultado *(Baseado nos dados das suas imagens)*:

```
 ________________________________________________
| especie                  | aquario             |
|________________________________________________|
| Lutra sumatrana          | Vasco da Gama       |
| Hexanchus griseus        | Infante D. Henrique |
| Torpedo torpedo          | Infante D. Henrique |
| Echinaster brasiliensis  | Bartolomeu Dias     |
|________________________________________________|
```

Utilizando a seguinte criação do `schema`:

```
CREATE TABLE aquario(id_aquario  INTEGER,
                     localizacao VARCHAR(100),
                     nome        VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE especie(id_especie      INTEGER,
                     nome_cientifico VARCHAR(100),
                     id_cat          INTEGER,
                     id_habitat      INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE aquario_habitat(id_aquario INTEGER,
                             id_habitat INTEGER,
                             adequacao  INTEGER);

insert into aquario(id_aquario, localizacao, nome)
values(1, 'NO', 'Vasco da Gama'),
      (2, 'N', 'Bartolomeu Dias'),
      (3, 'S', 'Infante D. Henrique');

insert into especie(id_especie, nome_cientifico, id_cat, id_habitat)
values(1, 'Lutra sumatrana', 9, 2),
      (2, 'Hexanchus griseus', 8, 1),
      (3, 'Torpedo torpedo', 7, 1),
      (4, 'Echinaster brasiliensis', 11, 3);

insert into aquario_habitat(id_aquario, id_habitat, adequacao)
values(1, 1, 10),
      (2, 1, 0),
      (3, 1, 100),
      (1, 2, 100),
      (2, 2, 90),
      (3, 2, 90),
      (1, 3, 0),
      (2, 3, 100),
      (3, 3, 0);
```

**EDIT**

Ou como foi pedido, adicionando na `query` que foi apresentada *(O `FROM` com várias tabelas é igual ao `INNER JOIN` só que a visualização é mais difícil)*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.nome,
                E.nome_cientifico
  FROM Aquario A,
       Especie E,
       Aquario_Habitat AH
 WHERE AH.id_habitat = E.id_habitat
   AND A.id_aquario = AH.id_aquario
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM aquario_habitat ah2
                   WHERE ah2.id_habitat = ah.id_habitat -- O que importa é o habitat
                     AND ah2.id_aquario <> ah.id_aquario -- Deve desconsiderar o mesmo aquário
                     AND ah2.adequacao > ah.adequacao); -- Caso existe de adequação maior, este deve ser descartado;
```

Comment: A ideia é que para cada espécie eu obtenha o habitat com mais percentagem de adequação. Por exemplo , para a especie com o id 1 corresponde ao habitat 2 e o que tem mais percentagem de adequação corresponde ao do Aquário 1

Comment: @SomosBenfica certo, mas o que deu de diferente no resultado dessa `query`?

Comment: Eu não percebo é o " Select 1" , o que é que isso faz ?

Comment: E sim isso da correcto , mas não há uma maneira de fazer isso completando o codigo que ja tinha na pergunta ? Ou só mesmo dessa maneira ?

Comment: @SomosBenfica da pra fazer mas a melhor forma é com `INNER JOIN`. O `SELECT 1` é só pra retornar um registro qualquer. Você só precisa saber se está retornando, não importa o campo. Enfim, adicionei, mas não é a melhor forma.